# Spring WebMVC - How to wire an interceptor for EULA check after successful login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC and Security to authenticate my web service.

I want the system to check that any newly authenticated users have accepted the EULA.  If EULA check is good then let them continue on their merry ways.

If EULA check fails then have them stop by the "/eula" page until they accept.

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class AssertEulaInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Value("eulaCookieName")
    private String cookieName;

    @javax.annotation.Resource(name = "EULAResource")
    private Resource eulaResource;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("EULA CHECK");
        Cookie cookie = extractCookie(cookieName, request.getCookies());

        if (assertEulaAccepted(request, response, handler, cookie)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/services/eula");
        }
    }
}
```

and in my servlet-context.xml file:

```
...
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/static/j_spring_security_check*" />
        <bean class="com.example.AssertEulaInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
...
```

I have also tried:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/static/j_spring_security_check*" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login*"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/eula*"/>
        <bean class="com.example.AssertEulaInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But this doesn't do the check.  ("EULA CHECK" never appears in console output.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use exclude-mapping

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/check-me-pattern"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/exclude-me-pattern"/>
        <bean class="com.example.MyInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: I have tried that .. I updated question to reflect other failed attempts.